# Different SHA1 result every time I check, bad drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sha1

I was attempting to download and run the Windows 10 Insider Preview, but after a few failed boots and installation errors, I decided to test the SHA1 sum before committing.

I noticed that every time I ran the SHA1 sum, the outcome was different!  I have a feeling it's a bad SSD that I've been having previous issues with (the OS installed on it will randomly crash or other applications will randomly crash).

Here's a snippet of the output:

```
chris@BigD:~/Downloads$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= 219ccf891c89be1ef83fe2b4d837d4bd1239137d
chris@BigD:~/Downloads$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= c8ab37fce87b089217e72ae5f84e223c5eb5c251
chris@BigD:~/Downloads$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= 1a820c22b66ffafba0da848e980cec998c22f563
chris@BigD:~/Downloads$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= a7f0834f048a25a9200c3aec4aee72be3576afaf
```

I then copied the file to a spinning disk and did the same thing:

```
chris@BigD:/media/Hades/Linux-Info$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= 94991975ebc3ee49d74b31a37bcb43fa5c66897a
chris@BigD:/media/Hades/Linux-Info$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= 94991975ebc3ee49d74b31a37bcb43fa5c66897a
chris@BigD:/media/Hades/Linux-Info$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= 94991975ebc3ee49d74b31a37bcb43fa5c66897a
chris@BigD:/media/Hades/Linux-Info$ openssl sha1 Windows10.iso 
SHA1(Windows10.iso)= 94991975ebc3ee49d74b31a37bcb43fa5c66897a
```

Has anyone else experienced things like this with their SSD?  Is this a common issue or did I get a faulty drive?

Comment: Dumb question: are you sure the download was actually finished ?

Comment: what model of SSD? how old is it?

Comment: Sounds like a failing drive. Get any important data off it ASAP.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.  I'm actually trying to move to Windows 10 as quick as possible (I had packed up my 8.1 disk/key into storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the obvious... Was the file being modified (still downloading) during the SSD checksums?

If not, it sounds like a faulty SSD.  Check the S.M.A.R.T. data.

Comment: Yes the download was complete. A SMART check says it "PASSED", but I'm skeptical.  It's a relatively new SSD but I got it dirt cheap.  If anyone's looking for an SSD to avoid: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0D9-0021-00005